# Using .translateExtent in D3 returns 'NaN' x & y values when zooming

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale, data-visualization

I want to prevent users from panning too far away from the maps I create. However, I'm struggling to apply the `.translateExtent()` function successfully.

The simplified example below (I replaced the map with a square) replicates the problem. The code works if I remove the `.translateExtent()` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #svg {
        background-color: rgb(239, 239, 244);
      }
      #shape {
        fill: rgb(0, 75, 122);
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }
      #shape:hover {
        fill: rgb(150, 30, 27);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var width = 300,
          height = 300;

      var container = d3.select("body").append("div");

      var svg = container.append("svg")
             .attr("id", "svg")
             .attr("width", width)
             .attr("height", height);

      var group = svg.append("g");

      var shape = group.append("rect")
               .attr("id", "shape")
               .attr("width", 150)
               .attr("height", 150)
               .attr("x", 75)
               .attr("y", 75);

      zoom = d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([1, 3])
          .translateExtent([0, 0], [width, height])
          .on("zoom", zoomed);

      svg.call(zoom);

      function zoomed() {
        change = d3.event.transform;
        console.log(change)
        group.attr("transform", "translate(" + [change.x, change.y] + ")scale(" + change.k + ")")
        group.select("#shape").style("stroke-width", (3 / change.k) + "px");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error message in the console is:

> Error:  attribute transform: Expected number,
>   "translate(NaN,NaN)scale(1)".

I can't understand why panning/zooming is returning 'NaN' values for x and y, but it has something to do with `.translateExtent()`. I feel there's an extra step I need to take that transforms the extent using the current scale value, but none of examples I saw online seemed to need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A D3.zoom `translateExtent` takes one array for input

> If extent is specified, sets the translate extent to the specified
>   array of points [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]]

you've provided two arrays:

```
.translateExtent([0, 0], [width, height])
```

Try nesting these in an array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #svg {
        background-color: rgb(239, 239, 244);
      }
      #shape {
        fill: rgb(0, 75, 122);
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }
      #shape:hover {
        fill: rgb(150, 30, 27);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <body>
    <script>
      var width = 300,
          height = 300;

      var container = d3.select("body").append("div");

      var svg = container.append("svg")
             .attr("id", "svg")
             .attr("width", width)
             .attr("height", height);

      var group = svg.append("g");

      var shape = group.append("rect")
               .attr("id", "shape")
               .attr("width", 150)
               .attr("height", 150)
               .attr("x", 75)
               .attr("y", 75);

      zoom = d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([1, 3])
          .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
          .on("zoom", zoomed);

      svg.call(zoom);

      function zoomed() {
        change = d3.event.transform;
        console.log(change)
        group.attr("transform", "translate(" + [change.x, change.y] + ")scale(" + change.k + ")")
        group.select("#shape").style("stroke-width", (3 / change.k) + "px");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh damn, thank you so much again! That's embarrassing - it's not the first time I've mistaken two square brackets as one ...